# Gensim installation problems

Tags: python, pip, gensim

I am trying to install gensim on a google cloud instance using:

> pip3 install gensim

and this is the stacktrace when I am trying to import gensim:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities, summarization
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gensim/models/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 30, in <module>
    from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaVowpalWabbit, LdaMallet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gensim/models/wrappers/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ldamallet import LdaMallet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py", line 43, in <module>
    from smart_open import smart_open
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/smart_open/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .smart_open_lib import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/smart_open/smart_open_lib.py", line 36, in <module>
    import boto.s3.key
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 33, in <module>
    import boto.utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 1216, in <module>
    boto.plugin.load_plugins(config)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plugin'
```

This is the linux version (output of lsb_release -a):

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

and this is the output of

> pip3 freeze

```
Cython==0.25.1
Flask==0.11.1
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.6.1
Werkzeug==0.11.11
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
boto==2.43.0
bz2file==0.98
chardet==2.3.0
click==6.6
colorama==0.3.2
decorator==3.4.0
gensim==0.13.3
html5lib==0.999
itsdangerous==0.24
lxml==3.4.0
matplotlib==1.4.2
nltk==3.2.1
nose==1.3.4
numexpr==2.4
numpy==1.11.2
pandas==0.14.1
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-apt==0.9.3.12
python-dateutil==2.2
pytz==2012c
requests==2.4.3
scipy==0.14.0
six==1.8.0
smart-open==1.3.5
stop-words==2015.2.23.1
tables==3.1.1
unattended-upgrades==0.1
urllib3==1.9.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

Can anybody give me pointers! This is very frustrating.

Comment: Have you tried installing using  "sudo easy_install -U gensim" ? for me pip never works but this solves the problem.

Comment: I tried it "easy-install-3.4 gensim" after pip3 uninstall but same error!

Answer (score 19):

had the same problem, in case anyone stumbles upon this: GCE is broken somehow

> pip install google-compute-engine

from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/issues/262

works

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it:

> sudo pip3 uninstall boto
>
> sudo pip3 install boto

It seemed to be a google compute cloud thing.

Comment: Getting error while uninstalling boto Cannot uninstall 'boto'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem mainly occurs because of garbage present in boto plugin or config file. 
So as suggested by @vJune, we need to uninstall the boto library then install it again. 
I solved this problem by just removing the python-boto package only.

On Google Compute Engine:

Step1: Uninstall the python-boto package

```
sudo apt-get remove python-boto
```

Step2: Install the python-boto library

```
sudo apt-get install python-boto
```